# String index out of range when referring to different if statements

Tags: python, string, indexing

I am making a calculator program for class and I am getting a string index out of range error when I refer to minus, multiply, and divide signs but do not get it for addition sign as I refer to addition first in my series of if/elif statements.

```
problem = ("123 * 456")
numLength = 0
placeCount = -1
for i in problem:
    placeCount = placeCount + 1
    if i == "0" or i == "1" or i == "2" or i == "3" or i == "4" or i == "5" or i == "6" or i == "7" or i == "8" or i == "9":
        numLength = numLength + 1
        holdingList.append(i)
    if i == " " or i == ")" and numLength > 0:
        theNum = concatenate_list_data(holdingList)
        if problem[placeCount - (numLength + 2)] == "+" or problem[placeCount + 1] == "+":
            theNum = int(theNum)
            adding.append(theNum)
            holdingList = []
            numLength = 0
            theNum = ""
        elif problem[placeCount - (numLength + 2)] == "-" or problem[placeCount + 1] == "-":
            theNum = int(theNum)
            subtracting.append(theNum)
            holdingList = []
            numLength = 0
            theNum = ""
        elif problem[placeCount - (numLength + 2)] == "*" or problem[placeCount + 1] == "*":
            theNum = int(theNum)
            multing.append(theNum)
            holdingList = []
            numLength = 0
            theNum = ""
        elif problem[placeCount - (numLength + 2)] == "/" or problem[placeCount + 1] == "/":
            theNum = int(theNum)
            dividing.append(theNum)
            holdingList = []
            numLength = 0
            theNum = ""
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/nick/Desktop/Programs/calculator.py", line 61, in <module>
      if problem[placeCount - (numLength + 2)] == "+" or problem[placeCount + 1] == "+":
    IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nick/Desktop/Programs/calculator.py", line 61, in <module>
    if problem[placeCount - (numLength + 2)] == "+" or problem[placeCount + 1] == "+":
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: What is the value of variable `problem`

Comment: How long is the test string you're inputting? If placeCount is 0 in your first iteration, then you subtract `3` from it and index into problem, what is at character `problem[-3]`?

Comment: Where does `problem` fit in?

Comment: problem is the input for the math problem I want to solve. problem = (123 * 456)

Comment: if the problem is addition the code works as intended for example problem = (123 + 456)

Comment: FYI, `if i == "1" or i == "2" or i == "3" ...` can be simplified to `if i in ["1", "2", "3", ...]`

Comment: It's not related to your problem, but you need parentheses here: `if (i == " " or i == ")") and numLength > 0:` because `and` has higher precedence than `or`.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] to allow the problem to be reproduced — which includes defining the value assigned to the `problem` variable.

Comment: Changed it thanks. I did not know about "and" having a higher precedence than "or"

Comment: @LeapyNick The code will only test `problem[placeCount + 1] == "+"` when there is no `+` in the problem string. But when you reach the last char in the string, `placeCount + 1` will go beyond it - so you get an index error. One way to fix this is to use `problem[placeCount:placeCount + 1]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is:

```
problem = '(123 * 456)'
```

When you get to the `)` at the end of the string, `problem[placeCount + 1]` is outside the string.

You don't get an error when the operator is `+` because logical operators do shortcutting. Since `problem[placeCount - (numLength + 2)] == "+"` is true, it never tries to evaluate `problem[placeCount + 1] == "+"`.

But when `problem[placeCount - (numLength + 2)] == "+"` is false, it tries to test `problem[placeCount + 1]`. This accesses outside the string and gets an error.

Change the test to:

```
if problem[placeCount - (numLength + 2)] == "+" or (placeCount < len(problem) - 1 and problem[placeCount + 1] == "+"):
```

and similarly for all the other operators.

Comment: Thank you! I would not have figured this out on my own